# Create machine learning model for simulation task

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, time-series, simulation

I have a very simple 2 dimensional software simulation of a ball that can roll down a hill. (see image)
The ball starts at the top of the hill (at x-position 0 and y-position 50)
and can roll down to either the left or the right side of the hill. The ball's and hill's properties (mass, material, etc.) stay constant but are unknown. Also the force that pushes the ball down the hill is unknown.
Moreover there is wind that either accelerates or decelerates the ball. The wind speed is known and can change every time.

[image]
I collected 1000 trials (i.e. rolling the ball down the hill 1000 times).
For each trial, I sampled the ball's position and the wind speed at every 10th millisecond and saved the data into a csv file.

The file looks like this:

```
trial_nr,direction,time(ms),wind(km/h),ball_position
0,       None,     0,       10,        0/50
0,       right,    10,      10,        5/45
0,       right,    20,      4,         8/30
0,       right,    30,      6,         10/25
0,       right,    40,      7,         15/15 <- stop position (label)

1,       None,     0,       7,         0/50
1,       right,    10,      8,         7/43
...
1,       right,    50,      3,         20/15 <- stop position (label)

2,       None,     0,       8,         0/50
2,       left,     10,      1,         -3/48
2,       left,     20,      0,         -4/47
...
2,       left,     60,      3,         -17/15 <- stop position (label)
...more trials...
```

What I want to do now is to predict the stop position of the ball for future trials.
Concretely, I want to train a machine learning model with this csv file.

When it is trained, it gets as input the direction/wind/ball_position of a trial of the first 30ms and based on this data it should predict an estimate where the ball will stop after it rolled down the hill. This is a supervised learning problem since the label is the stop position of the ball.
I was thinking of using a neural network that gets as input the feature vectors in the csv file. But the problem is that not every feature vector has a label associated. Only the last feature vector of every trial has a label (the stop position). So how can I solve the given problem?
Every help is very appreciated.